# Best way for getting users friends top rating with Redis SORTED SET

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have SORTED SET user_id:rating for every level in the game(2000+ levels). There is 2 000 000 users in set.
I need to create 2 ratings - first - all users top 100, second - top 5 friends each player

First can be solved very easily with ZRANGE

But there is a problem with second,  because in average - every user has 500 friends

There is 2 ways:

1) I can do 500 requests with ZSCORE\ZRANK and sort users on by backend (too many requests, bad performance)

2) I can create SORTED SET for each user and update it on background on every users update. (more data, more ram, more complex)

May be there are any others options I missed?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your main concern here should be your data model. Does every user have a sorted set of his friends?

I would recommend something like this:

users:{id}:friends         values as the ids of friends
users:scoreboard           values as the users ids and score as the rating
                           of each

As an answer to your first concern, you can consider using pipelines, which will reduce the number of requests drastically, none the less you will still need to handle ordering the results.

The better answer for you problem would be, in case you have the two sorted sets as described earlier: 
Get the intersection between the two, using the "zinterstore" command and storing the result in a sorted set created solely for this purpose. As a result, the new sorted set will contain all the user's friends ids with their rating as the score (need to be careful here since you will need to specify the score of the new sorted set, it can either be the SUM, MIN or MAX of the scores).
ref: http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore

At this point using a simple "zrevrangebyscore" and specifying a limit, will leverage the sorted result you are looking for.